# A generic error in GDI+ with ToolStrip in ManagerRenderMode

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, gdi+, 64-bit

I have a vb.net form with ToolStrip menu

```
RenderMode - ManagerRenderMode
LayoutStyle - HorizontalStackWithOverflow
```

My development environment is .net 4.0, VS2010, windows 7 x64; but occasionally I am getting next error [image: error]

```
A generic error occurred in GDI+.
Stacktrace:   at System.Drawing.Graphics.CheckErrorStatus(Int32 status)
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brush brush, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height)
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brush brush, Rectangle rect)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripProfessionalRenderer.FillWithDoubleGradient(Color beginColor, Color middleColor, Color endColor, Graphics g, Rectangle bounds, Int32 firstGradientWidth, Int32 secondGradientWidth, LinearGradientMode mode, Boolean flipHorizontal)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripProfessionalRenderer.RenderToolStripBackgroundInternal(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripProfessionalRenderer.OnRenderToolStripBackground(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripRenderer.DrawToolStripBackground(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: Are you by any chance dynamically creating ToolStrip instances? (That's what we do, and we see the same problem)

Comment: No, that ToolStrip was created using Designer. The only thing that one of item ToolStripButton with picture Alignment property was set to the Right.

Answer (score 0):

I beleave that error is due to the memory starvation. This happen when application had consumed almost all available memory and nothing has been left for GDI+ to perform properly. GDI+ does not report that issue corectly.